# Angular 2 multiselect - hide "Select All" option after filtered results

Tags: html, typescript

I have an Angular 2 multiselect component that I have set to searchable. However, after a search string is entered a new option appears above the filtered options - "Select All Filtered Results" Is there any way to remove this option from appearing?

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="subAgencyDropdownList" [(ngModel)]="subAgencySelectedItems"
    [settings]="subAgencyDropdownSettings" (ngModelChange)="onSubAgencySelection($event)"
    class="agency-select">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

.

```
this.subAgencyDropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: true,
    enableSearchFilter: true,
    classes: 'multiselect'
};
```

[image]